# From what kind of insect might these eggs be

Tags: species-identification, entomology, eggs

Does anybody know what kind of insect might have laid these eggs:[image]

The photo was taken a few days ago in Limburg, Belgium near a pasture with some goats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are likely moth eggs... moths have a tendency to attach their eggs on metal screens that you might have in your windows or doors.

Here is a video of a moth laying eggs on glass:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2zf1J8CZdg

Here is a video of a moth laying eggs on a metal screen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKHReVNAMYw

Here are photos of eggs on a wire fence, believed to be moth eggs:
https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2013/09/19/possibly-moth-eggs-deer-fence/

And another example of moth eggs on a metal wire:
https://hardtocomebylifestyle.wordpress.com/2014/08/31/moth-eggs/